# C# DataGridView Color text of single row

Tags: c#, datagridview, coding-style

I have a DataGridView that has a class as its DataSource.

The class contains an ID string, 2x DateTimes and a Boolean.

I have written some code to change the text of a row that matches an ID I pass to method to Red, but nothing I have tried works.

This is what I have so far:

```
public void ShowInstanceAsTerminated(String id)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvRow in dgvRIM.Rows)
    {
        if (dgvRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == id)
        {
            dgvRow.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

This is one of many variations of code I have tried, but the cells in question never change!!

Thanks
Neil

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this format:

```
dgvRIM.Rows[myRow].Cells[0].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

If you want to set the entire row, loop over all cells.

Comment: +1 - this was the same concept I was trying to get across, but you phrased it better.

Comment: This didn't work for me.

During a debug session, I can see the style applied to the cell, but it never actually changes. Next time around it still isn't set.

I wonder if I have to set that row to be the row after changing it. Something like:

dgvRIM.Row[myrow] = newRow;

Hmmmm.... any thoughts whilst I give it a go?

Comment: How about adding a line of code after changing the color to force the datagridview to update?  The following code should do that:

 dvgRIM.Invalidate();

Comment: My other idea threw an exception.

dvgRIM.Invalidate(); doidn't work either.

I don't see what I am doing wrong really.. its a curious one!

I have added a CellStyle_Changed and that hasn't yet been hit!!

Comment: If you can create a mini example of the problem small enough to post here (or if you can post a link), I'm happy to have a look at the whole thing.

Comment: I created a small forms app to test my code... and it worked fine.

So I think I must be re-binding the datasource somewhere that resets any changes...

Comment: Sorted it!

I was indeed setting the DataSource in a second place.. Doh!!

All good and I am using the code as Eric J. suggested.

Thanks

Comment: Good answer. Is there a more efficient way to do this than doing all cells individually? I would expect a degredation in performance upon refresh if there were many rows in this datagrid. Any ideas?

Comment: @chonerman: I would not expect that simply setting the property is going to be very expensive.  Rows that are not physically visible should not incur a rerendering cost until they actually become visible.  I would test performance for your definition of "many rows" before trying to optimize the problem.

Comment: @EricJ. thanks for you input. I have a production ticketing system being used now that has around 3k rows and growing. I did find a way to set the entire row rather than each individual cell and it did help the performance slightly. I will have to limit my return query as the number of tickets increases over time so that the rendering doesn't bog down the users. ( ex. ticket_dgv1.Rows[d].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Pink; )

Comment: @chonerman: I agree that you should likely limit the result set, not so much due to performance but because it's unlikely that 3000+ rows in the UI will be useful to an end user.  That is simply too much to scroll through.

Comment: @EricJ. agreed. However this is the backend gui that I am dealing with. The front end is a web application and is paginated and limited.

Answer (score 6):

Use the DataGridView's CellFormatting event to make changes to individual cells that compose a row.

Something like this (beware, not tested):

```
private void dgvRIM_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) {
  if (dgvRIM.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == id) {
    e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1. Vivek, he cannot use e.Value, he wants to check the value of the row's first cell which is not necessarily the current cell.

Comment: This works, and sets the style of all the cells of the row without looping through every cell

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine

```
private void grid1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
  DataGridViewRow row = grid1.Rows[e.RowIndex];// get you required index
  // check the cell value under your specific column and then you can toggle your colors
  row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

This works for .NET 4.0 and upwards at least.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the individual cells.

This is VB code lifted from an app where I am able to successfully do this, but it shouldn't be to hard to convert this to c#.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables("AddressChanges").Rows.Count - 1
                If ds.Tables("AddressChanges").Rows(i)("iSeriesAddress").ToString <> ds.Tables("AddressChanges").Rows(i)("CSIAddress").ToString() Then
                    Me.dgAddressDiscrepancies.Rows(i).Cells("iSeriesAddress").Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                    Me.dgAddressDiscrepancies.Rows(i).Cells("CSIAddress").Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                End If
Next
```

Comment: He want's to change the Row's ForeColor, this can be done without having to modify each cell's ForeColor/BackColor.

Comment: In theory you should be right, but in practice, I've found that it doesn't work.  Unless something has changed, that is.. My code was .Net 2.0, so it's possible the DataGridView has been updated, but as he said in his question, if you try to apply it to a row, it throws no error, but does not change the color, either.  At any rate, my answer is changing the backcolor, not the forecolor but the concept is the same.  @Eric J answered with the same idea but in a better, clearer form.

Comment: @David Stratton: I've just tested it and it does work (see my answer). For what reason it didn't work in your case? Why would setting the ForeColor for the individual cells work better??

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code (setting the `ForeColor` with `DefaultCellStyle`) and it DOES work (with .NET 3.5, but I don't think Winforms has evolved since 2.0).

Now I don't know why it doesn't work for you... maybe you call the code before rows are added, or you reload the rows after your code is called??

Either way, you're probably better off with Jay Riggs's solution, as it will work even if you add new rows afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution lies in WHEN you set the color, not the method in which you do so.  Several different events have been suggested and some will indeed work.  One of the problems with using either the cellformatting, databindingcomplete, or even paint events is that they get fired multiple times.  From what I've gathered, there is an issue with the datagridview control in that you cannot change the color of any of the cells until AFTER the form has been shown.  Thus methods that run, or events that fire before Shown() is called will not change the color.  The events that are sited as the solution to the problem usually work, but since they're called many times, may not be the most efficient answer.

Probably the simplest solution to the issue is to put your code to fill/color your grids in the Shown() method of your form instead of the constructor.  Below is a link to a post in the msdn forums that tipped me off to the solution, it's marked as the answer about 3/4 of the way down the page.

[MSDN forums post with the Solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/31ef832b-2fe2-4554-bf0c-8495f9e85ede/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a bug with `TabControl` that **when it has more than one tab**, `cellstyles` that are created with code are only applied to the **first tab's DataGridView**, so to solve the problem you can move your `DataGridView` to the first tab or you can use the TabControl's `SelectedIndexChanged` event and put your styling code in this event .